# Vue http setting root url fails

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

Am trying to set the root url in vue http but it fails

```
main.js

import VueResource from 'vue-resource'
Vue.use(VueResource);
Vue.http.options.root = 'http://example.com';
```

Now in my components

```
this.$http.get("url").then()....//fails
```

But the above doesnt use the root url `example.com`

Comment: maybe add forward slash `/`

Comment: What is the failed output?

Comment: the root domain is not getting set.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var exampleResource = Vue.resource('http://example.com')
var responseData

exampleResource.get().then(response => {
  responseData = response.body
})
```